# Create new lists of the shortest and longest words in an existing list - Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I know there is a better way to do this but I can't seem to find it. As you can see below I am getting the longest and shortest results but only because I know what the longest and shortest words are and I then input a condition....but what if I didn't know the longest and shortest words... hope I am making myself clear. Just started with programming so have no prior experience. Many thanks for any help!

```
names = [ "Brian", "jake", "Jason", "Brad", "Tony", "jimmy", "Bobby", "Stevie"] 

long = []
short = []

for name in names:
    if len(name) <= 4:
        short.append(name)
        print "Short names: ", short

for name in names:
    if len(name) >=6:
        long.append(name)
        print "long names: ", long
```

Comment: Hint: `min(len(s) for s in names)` and `max(len(s) for s in names)` gives you length of shortest and longest strings in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the len of the shortest and longest name with

```
len_short = min([len(x) for x in names])
len_long = max([len(x) for x in names])
```

These variables can then replace `4` and `6` in your code

---

```
names = [ "Brian", "jake", "Jason", "Brad", "Tony", "jimmy", "Bobby", "Stevie"] 

long = []
short = []
len_short = min([len(x) for x in names])  # this will be 4
len_long = max([len(x) for x in names])  # this will be 6

for name in names:
    if len(name) <= len_short:
        short.append(name)
        print "Short names: ", short

for name in names:
    if len(name) >= len_long:
        long.append(name)
        print "long names: ", long
```

Comment: Cheers Tim, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Many thanks Tim! I staretd to play around with your answer to ger a better understanding and I tried this:                                                                                                            for x in names:
 len_short = min(len(x))
for x in names:
            len_long= max(len(x))
and it didnt work!

Comment: Cheers for the comprehensive reply Tim! Got a better understanding now! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) built-in function with `len` as `key` argument.

```
>>> names = [ "Brian", "jake", "Jason", "Brad", "Tony", "jimmy", "Bobby", "Stevie"]
>>> max(names, key=len)
'Stevie'
>>> min(names, key=len)
'jake'
>>> len(max(names, key=len))
6
>>> len(min(names, key=len))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to sort the list by the length of the names, and then filter out those names that match the length of the longest and shortest words:

```
sorted_names = sorted(names, key=len)
short_names = [i for i in sorted_names if len(i) == len(sorted_names[0])]
long_names = [i for i in sorted_names if len(i) == len(sorted_names[-1])]
```